# Notation of a probability distribution over a vector

Tags: probability-distributions, vectors

I'm reading [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04444.pdf) and I'm not sure to understand this equation:  $b=Pr(y|h)$ where $y$ is, according to the article, "a 52-dimension one-hot vector encoding [the player $y$] cards" (page 5, *Problem Setup*). I guess the authors mean $y$ is a vector of 52 elements with 13 of them are 1 and the others are 0.

$h$ is a 52x2 matrix. I'm not sure what is $b$.

According to my knowledge, $b$ is the probability distribution over a vector with $\binom{52}{13}$ possible combinations so $b$ should have $\binom{52}{13}$ elements.

But, later in the article (page 5, *Model Architecture*), I can read that we can add $b$ to $x$ ($x$ is a 52 dimension vector). So I guess now $b$ is also a 52 dimension vector with x<sub>n</sub> is $P(y_{n} = 1)$.

My questions are: do I misunderstand the equation? Or the authors of the article wanted to simplify the probability distribution? What is $b$?

**Note:** I don't want to know what $b$ represents but I want to know how $b$ is mathematically represented.

**Note 2:** The point of the article is to use a POMDP to create a bridge bidding system. So, $b$ is the *belief* of the player, $y$ is the unobserved environment state and $h$ is the history of the bids.

Comment: Vectors have a length, but not a dimension.

Comment: @Wuestenfux I'm surprised because it's written, about the $y$ vector: "is a 52-dimension one-hot vector encoding the 13 cards [of the player y]".

Comment: @Wuestenfux Saying "an $n$-dimensional vector" is absolutely standard.

Comment: Thanks. I think it might help to cite some equations or page numbers in the article so that readers can find the relevant passages a little more quickly.

Comment: @littleO It's done.